# How to call custom phtmls in cms pages of magento 2.3.6 p1EE

Tags: magento-2.3

How can I call custom phtml in cms pages or cms blocks of magento 2.3.6 p1 enterprise Version.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the block tag in cms pages e.g.

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Your_Module::your/template.phtml'}}
```

You can use default block template class `Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template` or define your own.

For cms blocks you can play with widgets. Probably you will need to create your own widget just to render passed phtml.

```
{{widget type="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" template="widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="1"}}
```